# C# - Insert Multiple Records at once to AS400

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, odbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a problem like this:
1. I retrieve data from MySQL using C# ASP .Net. -- done --
2. All data from no.1 will be inserted into table on AS400. -- I got an error on this step --
Error message says that `ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>.`. It's true that I used semicolon to separate queries with each others, but it's not allowed. I've Googling but I can't find the solution.
My question is what the `<END-OF-STATEMENT>` means of that error message..?
Here is my source code.

```
private static void doInsertDOCADM(MySqlConnection conn)
    {
        // Get Temporary table
        String query = "SELECT * FROM TB_T_DOC_TEMPORARY_ADM";
        DataTable dt = CSTDDBUtil.ExecuteQuery(query);

        OdbcConnection as400Con = null;
        as400Con = CSTDDBUtil.GetAS400Connection();
        as400Con.Open();

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int counter = 1, maxInsertLoop = 50;

            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = as400Con;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText += "INSERT INTO DCDLIB.WDFDOCQ VALUES " + "(?,?,?,?);";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["PROD_MONTH"].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["NEW_MAIN_DEALER_CD"].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["MODEL_SERIES"].ToString();
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = dr["MODEL_CD"].ToString();


                    if (counter < maxInsertLoop)
                    {
                        counter++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        counter = 1;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.CommandText = "";
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }

                if (counter > 1) cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Notes: I used this way (Collect some queries first, and then execute those query) to improve the performance of my application.

Comment: Any reason you cannot just do an INSERT-command pr line instead of building a giant single command with multiple inserts?

Comment: I'm afraid that the performance will be not good. I've tried INSERT-command per line on MySQL, and it's worst than when I build a giant single command.

Comment: That is most likely because the JDBC-driver autocommits unless you instruct it otherwise.

Comment: For JDBC read #C-technology-providing SQL tunnel.

Comment: IBM has not sold an AS/400 since 2000.  Chances are you have an IBM Power System, and it running IBM i 6.1, not OS/400.  IBM built Watson on Power7. You wouldn't obsolete terms to describe your C# environment as running Windows ME on a PS/2.  Please don't do the same to your more powerful Power System.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Clockwork-Muse pointed out, the problem is that you can only run a single SQL statement in a command. The iSeries server does not handle multiple statements at once.

If your iSeries server is running V6R1 or later, you can use block inserts to insert multiple rows. I'm not sure if you can do so through the ODBC driver, but since you have Client Access, you should be able to install the iSeries ADO.NET driver. There are not many differences between the ADO.NET iSeries driver and the ODBC one, but with ADO.NET you get access to iSeries specific functions.

With the ADO.NET driver, multiple insert become a simple matter of :

```
    using (iDB2Connection connection = new iDB2Connection(".... connection string ..."))
        {
            // Create a new SQL command
            iDB2Command command = 
                new iDB2Command("INSERT INTO MYLIB.MYTABLE VALUES(@COL_1, @COL_2", connection);

            // Initialize the parameters collection
            command.DeriveParameters();

            // Insert 10 rows of data at once
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                // Here, you set your parameters for a single row
                command.Parameters["@COL_1"].Value = i;
                command.Parameters["@COL_2"].Value = i + 1;
                // AddBatch() tells the command you're done preparing a row
                command.AddBatch();
            }

            // The query gets executed
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

There is also some reference code provided by IBM to do block inserts using VB6 and ODBC, but I'm not sure it can be easily ported to .NET : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaik%2Frzaikextfetch.htm

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 - I'd forgotten about the whole 'batch' bit.  I guess I was a little to spoiled by how you can deal with embedded SQL on the RPG side.

Comment: Well, I found out about it while answering this question :) I had the same issue a while ago and finally settled for 'row-by-agonizing-row'... But since then we migrated to V6R1 and I hadn't checked for the new features of the .NET driver.

Comment: We do use block inserts, by adding multiple records to the recordset, then update the recordset.

Comment: You should be using the newest driver with service pack installed, either v6.1 or v7.1.  Newer drivers include improvements, and are backward compatible with systems on several prior releases, but older drivers are not recommended for newer systems.

Answer (score 2):

When it says `<END-OF-STATEMENT>` it means about what it says - it wants that to be the end of the executed statement.  I don't recall if the AS/400 allows multiple statements per execution unit (at all), but clearly it's not working here.  And the driver isn't dealing with it either.

Actually, you have a larger, more fundamental problem; specifically, you're `INSERT`ing a row at a time (usually known as row-by-agonizing-row).  DB2 allows a comma-separated list of rows in a `VALUES` clause (so, `INSERT INTO <table_name> VALUES(<row_1_columns>), (<row_2_columns>)`) - does the driver you're using allow you to provide arrays (either of the entire row, or per-column)?  Otherwise, look into using extract/load utilities for stuff like this - I can guarantee you that this will speed up the process.

Comment: Still can't work :( I've tried your suggestion, I got the same error `ERROR [42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token , was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>.`

Comment: How do I check the driver was provided arrays or not,.? I'm using iSeries Access ODBC Driver.

Comment: As far as I know, the iSeries SQL engine (DB2 UDB which has some differences with DB2 LUW) does not allow multiple inserts through arrays. You have to use block inserts, which can be done via the low-level ODBC api or the ADO.NET iSeries driver (which is included in the iSeries Client Access install package).