# bulk insert with DB2 iSeries (C#)

Tags: c#, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to make a bulk insert into db2 using C#.

```
CREATE TABLE tsdta.ftestbk1
(
   NUM numeric(8,0),
   TEXT varchar(30)
)
```

And here is my test code:

```
using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries;

...

using (iDB2Connection connection = new iDB2Connection("xxx"))
{
   string sql = @"insert into tsdta.ftestbk1 
                  values
                  (
                     @num,
                     @text
                  )";
   connection.Open();
   iDB2Command command = connection.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   command.CommandText = sql;
   command.Prepare();
   command.DeriveParameters();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
      command.Parameters.Add("@num", i);
      command.Parameters.Add("@text", $"some text for {i}");
      command.AddBatch();
   }

   int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   connection.Close();
}
```

When I execute the code, in the table are only NULL values.

```
 NUM   | TEXT
------------
<null> |<null>
<null> |<null>
<null> |<null>
<null> |<null>
<null> |<null>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a Db2 instance to double check, I am doing this from memory and some old code but I have the following which is running in our prod env for me (I've adjusted it to look like yours)

```
using (iDB2Connection connection = new iDB2Connection("xxx"))
{
    iDB2Command command = new iDB2Command("INSERT INTO TSDTA.FTESTBK1 VALUES(@NUM, @TEXT", connection);

    // Initialize the parameters collection
    command.DeriveParameters();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        command.Parameters["@NUM"].Value = i;
        command.Parameters["@TEXT"].Value = $"some text {i}";
        command.AddBatch();
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

We had a similar problem at the time and I got the original code from here...

[C# - Insert Multiple Records at once to AS400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729267/c-sharp-insert-multiple-records-at-once-to-as400)

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed the parameter access in the for-loop but I have a strange behaviour. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException here: command.Parameters["@TEXT"].Value = $"some text {i}".
After debugging the command parameters I found out that DeriveParameters() method prepares ParameterName "@TEXT\r\n" from the sql-string. After changing the sql-string as in your example it works.
So. Never format a sql-string as I have done in my example :-)